# How to sum array values of same key and save it to database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

```
array (
  '' => 
  array (
0 => '0.0000',
1 => '0.0330',
2 => '1100.8486',
3 => '0.3560',
4 => '3.9032',
5 => '0.0000',
6 => '0.8571',
7 => '0.0000',
8 => '0.6660',
9 => '4538.2989',
10 => '0.0000',
11 => '0.1385',
12 => '0.0000',
13 => '0.0000',
14 => '0.0989',
15 => '0.0000',
16 => '0.0000',
17 => '0.6132',
18 => '0.0000',
19 => '12288.1236',
  ),
  'ads_bottom' => 
  array (
    0 => '0.0000',
    1 => '0.0000',
    2 => '5.7823',
    3 => '0.0000',
    4 => '0.0000',
     5 => '0.0000',
    6 => '0.0000',
    7 => '0.0000',
    8 => '0.0000',
    9 => '25.3049',
    10 => '0.0000',
    11 => '0.0000',
    12 => '0.0000',
    13 => '0.0000',
     14 => '0.0000',
    15 => '0.0000',
    16 => '0.0000',
    17 => '101.6482',
  ),
  'ads_side' => 
  array (
    0 => '0.0000',
    1 => '0.0000',
    2 => '1.4440',
    3 => '0.0000',
    4 => '0.0000',
    5 => '0.0000',
    6 => '0.0000',
    7 => '0.0000',
    8 => '0.0000',
    9 => '11.0701',
    10 => '0.0000',
    11 => '0.0000',
    12 => '0.0000',
    13 => '0.0000',
    14 => '0.0000',
    15 => '0.0000',
    16 => '0.0000',
    17 => '29.8609',
      ),
  'ads_top' => 
  array (
    0 => '0.0000',
    1 => '0.0000',
    2 => '50.6098',
    3 => '0.0000',
    4 => '0.0000',
    5 => '0.0000',
    6 => '0.0000',
    7 => '0.0000',
    8 => '0.0000',
    9 => '214.3004',
    10 => '0.0000',
    11 => '0.0000',
    12 => '0.0000',
    13 => '0.0000',
    14 => '0.0000',
    15 => '0.0000',
    16 => '0.0000',
    17 => '548.1496',
      ),
      'image_ad_top' => 
  array (
    0 => '0.0000',
    1 => '0.0000',
    2 => '3.3757',
    3 => '0.0000',
    4 => '0.0000',
    5 => '0.0000',
    6 => '0.0000',
    7 => '0.0000',
    8 => '0.0000',
    9 => '17.3996',
   10 => '0.0000',
   11 => '0.0000',
   12 => '0.0000',
   13 => '0.0000',
   14 => '0.0726',
   15 => '0.0000',
   16 => '0.0000',
   17 => '0.0000',
   18 => '57.1042',
  ),
      'page_next' => 
  array (
    0 => '0.0000',
    1 => '0.0000',
    2 => '60.7305',
    3 => '0.0000',
    4 => '0.0000',
    5 => '0.0000',
    6 => '0.0000',
    7 => '150.2470',
    8 => '0.0000',
    9 => '0.0000',
   10 => '0.0000',
   11 => '0.0000',
   12 => '0.0000',
   13 => '0.0000',
   14 => '0.0330',
   15 => '451.5058',
    ),
 )
```

How to sum array values of same key and save it to database ? I am stuck in the process of doing foreach for the result
I tried to use for each for these but can't seem to get the right output that I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Use nested foreach statement and create an array with the same keys. For ex,

```
$temp = array();
foreach($main_array as $key=>$val){
    foreach ($val as $key2=>$val2) {
        if(!isset($temp[$key2]))
            $temp[$key2]=0;
        $temp[$key2]+= $val2; 
    }
}
//$temp will hold a row of same keys sum
```

Comment: foreach($result as $key => $val){
                    $acc[$key] += $val;
            }
            I did something like this

Comment: Did you try using nested(two) foreach statement as in the updated answer?